# Duplicate user account being created in Windows-8

Tags: windows, windows-8, users

Before I synced my Windows 8 Pro with Windows Live, the login screen displayed one user account that I created with my username. After sync, two accounts are being displayed, both with the same username.

I assumed one of them uses Windows Live credentials to login, and the other uses local credentials, but there's no way to tell as they are both identical and I am able to login to both, using the same (local) password.

When I went into the Users and Groups section in the control panel, only one user account (local) is present. Where does the other one come from, and how do I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a similar problem but different. I've created two local user accounts on my machine (Win 8 Pro 64 bit), one admin and one normal user, different passwords. These both appear once in the Manage Users screen along with the disabled Guest account. But when I go to the pre-login user switching screen I get smaller duplicate icons/buttons of both accounts. It's pretty annoying, but both buttons for each of the two accounts do log in correctly. Can't do a screen clip there to show you.

Edit: 
I just found the answer on another site. It was my Toshiba Fingerprint software that was doing it.  A quick uninstall fixed that problem (but I lose fingerprint capability, as there's no update from Toshiba yet!). I'm told that OEM facial recognition software can also cause it.

Comment: Ah I see! I do have Fast Access Facial Recognition software on my Dell XPS. Will try uninstalling it and see it it works. Can you share the link to that site?

Comment: I have a friend who saw this and it was also the fingerprint scanner.  Removing it solved his issue.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the control panel: swipe in from the right (or press Win+C), then click on Control Panel
2. Click on User Accounts and Family Safety
3. Click User Accounts
4. Click Manage Another Account

This will show all accounts linked to this computer, including both local and Microsoft accounts. Local accounts will be noted as such, and Microsoft accounts will display the associated email address. You can click on any account to delete it or change its privileges. You can reset passwords for local accounts, but not for Microsoft accounts.

[image: windows 8 manage user accounts]

Comment: Note: this can be found with `Win + W`: Configure Advanced User Profile Properties

Comment: But it still doesn't explain why i'm able to login with the same password to both accounts.

Comment: @Jay does it show the same Microsoft account twice, or is one of them the local account? It's possible that your Microsoft account and local account just happen to have the same password.

Comment: To figure out which is which, you could rename the local account to `<username> LOCAL`, and see which is which on the login screen.

Comment: @nhinkle No, i set different passwords for both. But the username for both accounts is the same. Will try it out and update this thread later today.

Comment: @nhinkle If you're still around... I checked the Manage User accounts page. There was only one account (admin) and one user account which is turned off. No sign of the Microsoft account

Answer (score 0):

I held off on posting this (since *Manage Accounts* seemed to be the way to go), but maybe this will help.

While you're logged in using the Live credentials, from the `Charms bar / Settings / PC Settings / Users`, try `Switch[ing] to a local account` and selecting the other account:

[image: 1]

Answer (score -2):

Had exactly same problem. I simply un-installed my Cyber You-Cam 5 and the duplicates vanished all together.