# Windows 8 Login Screen shows two login tiles for same user account

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts, login-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate user account being created in Windows-8](https://superuser.com/questions/495158/duplicate-user-account-being-created-in-windows-8)

Whenever I create a new user account the Login Screen of Windows 8 shows two login tiles for the same user account. As I found both have the same password and permissions, is there any way to remove the duplicate login tile ? Or something wrong the settings of user accounts ?

This might help you to understand the issue.

[image]

This is not a duplicate of [Duplicate user account being created in Windows-8](https://superuser.com/questions/495158/duplicate-user-account-being-created-in-windows-8) because I do not have duplicate accounts in control panel like the other question did.
[image]

Comment: Please do not edit out the Possible Duplicate notice. If you want to **add** anything to the question, feel free to do it.

Comment: Personally, looking at this, I suspect the duplicate account picture on the login screen is an artefact of the facial recognition software which you've installed but not enabled, so this is less likely to be an exact duplicate as the earlier questions I can find.

Comment: There is no clear answer like this the Duplicate question. Any way I will try this if it works. Thank You.